# Venn diagrams with heatmap

Tags: venn-diagram

I generated 40 different Venn diagrams that each represent a specific 'trial' of an experiment (they are actually different samples in a genetic study).
The Venn diagrams represent the overlap between 5 different sets (5-way Venns) and they are generated directly as SVGs from Python by replacing the labels in the [example Venn from Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File%3aSymmetrical_5-set_Venn_diagram.svg).

My question is: how would you proceed to create a heatmap of the density of every set intersection. In other words, I would like to add a 2D color heatmap over the Venn diagram which would represent the density of the different regions of the diagram over all the samples.
Alternatively, a 3D density map could be used, which would give me a new dimension for projecting the density. I thought of using the Gaussian probability density function for the z.